# Why can enemies see me when I'm cloaked?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am currently near the beginning of the game (Mars Archives), and I'm at the point in the area where I ride a tram. Soon after, a fight ensues. To reposition myself to a better spot during the fight, I've used Tactical Cloak to become invisible and move to the other side of the room. However, a few times when I have done this, enemies have shot at me.

I realize that there's some fade time involved where I'm still partially visible by enemies, but even after I'm fully cloaked, I still occasionally get shot directly in the head and die.

My Shepard is level 33, has level 5 Tactical Cloak, and I'm playing on Hardcore difficulty.

**Is this a result of me playing on a harder difficulty, or can certain enemies detect invisibility? If so, is there some way for me to tell which enemies can and cannot see me?**

Comment: Are you sure you weren't just in the line of fire between enemies and a squadmate directly behind you?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I recall one incident where both squadmates were in the tram, at which point I cloaked and moved far outside to the right. I was lining up my shot when I got shot at by a single bullet to the head and died.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Confirmed that I'm still being purposely targetted when cloaked. Ravagers aim right for me when I'm out of cover.

Comment: It's *possible* that their aim gets worse, but the most simple of experiments shows that their movements are *not* affected. This would seem to include assault troopers. I first noticed this on Mars, where you open a door and encounter anumber of oblivious troopers. In my attempt to imitate kasumi (with my squad placed around the corner), I both agroed the enemies, and caused them to move into the back room to get me, before my cloak had ran out. After the group was down to a pair of guardians, I ordered my squad away again, and had them walking around in circles shooting at a cloaked shepard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you are cloaked you're not completely invisible.  As far as the cloak goes you'll see a little field of electricity every now and then.  Also, certain enemies are smarter than others; assault troopers won't see you unless you fire but let's say a banshee or a phantom were there, they would most likely be able to see the background morph as you move.

Comment: You're about as invisible as hunters, which is to say so so... At a distance you're probably fine, especially if you're not moving and there are things for them to shoot at!

Answer (score 0):

Distance and position play a factor in cloaking. If you cloak at point blank range, enemies can still tell where you are. Moving around will help confuse them some but you really should run away and try to break line of sight. The more distance you have, the more confused and less likely to accurately target you the enemy will be. If they don't see you cloak, you're good until they get on top of you. Also you're still there so if you brush up and make contact with an enemy or they do by bumping into them, that's a sign for them to start shooting and alerts them to your presence.